# Unexpected behaviour when removing tags

Tags: bug, tags

When removing a not yet selected <kbd>tag</kbd> from the tag list, by selecting the word and pressing backspace, instead of the selected text being removed, it simply *untags* the previous tag and removes the selection of the text. See:

[image: Gif]

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Add one or more tags.
2. Start typing after the tags.
3. Select the typed text.
4. Press backspace to delete text.

Comment: Oh, it's a duplicate from a post from 2015!!!